# Android app styling

Tags: android, android-styles

i want to make my android apps very stylish, i.e. styling controls like EditText, Button, spinner, etc... can anyone provide me samples to do this.

Thanks,
nag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) is an excellent post about anything you can do to style your application. However, not everything can be styled, but most parts of the UI can surely be changed. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If u want to have your apps very stylish just add your required resources(.png Images) in res/drawable and use wherever u want as a background(layouts,edittexts,buttons etc) so that you can have a better look and feel.